# convert a file into JSON to use in D3 for visualization

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have a file that has content that looks like this:

```
object node {
name swing120;
from 679-1025;
to spt128-1043;
configuration lineover-1bc2-ac;
}
object switch {
name spectializer120;
phases BN;
from spt128-1043;
to 678-1022;
status OPEN;
}
```

How to convert it into a JSON file so I can convert the JSON file into a graphic using d3.js visualization (by importing the JSON file). I tried some online to-JSON converters but did not do the job quite right. I thought of writing a python script to convert it into a .csv file and import that .csv file into D3 but by reading D3 documentation, converting it into JSON and importing it into D3 makes more sense.

Comment: What's is it currently structured as? Perhaps there is a parser for it already.

Comment: @Xero The entire file has thousands of various objects like `node` and `switch` in above example. Reading through a 100,000 like file and drawing a flowchart manually is very difficult. So, I want to convert that into some kind of a chart. The entire file structure looks just like the above.

Comment: Well, I mean, what's the name of the structure? For example, JSON can be parsed an wrote because it has a certain notion.  What is the notion you're using called, or is it made up?

Comment: @Xero One of the softwares I work with spits out files with data that looks like the above. So I am not sure what's the name of the structure is.

Comment: @Xero I was thinking, instead of converting this into JSON file, can I parse this is javascript?

Comment: Your process would be more like `Unknown Structure -> JSON -> JavaScript`...  You'd turn the file into JSON (somehow), then parse the JSON into JavaScript.

Comment: You probably want to write a parser in python to convert to JSON. You're fairly close already; just need better naming/formatting.

Comment: @SrinGupta, if you are asking "can I use JavaScript to parse a text file into JavaScript objects?", the answer is always going to be yes.  But, this question isn't specific enough for stackoverflow.  Start writing the parser, when you get stuck come back with your **specific** problem.

Comment: I will start writing the parser to convert to JSON.